# Branch IO Android SDK initialization error

Tags: android, branch.io

I try to setup Branch.io on android, but get an error:

> BranchSDK: Warning: Please enter your branch_key in your project's
>   res/values/strings.xml!

Manifest:

```
<!-- Branch init -->
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="@string/branch_key" />
<!-- Branch testing (TestMode "true" to simulate fresh installs on dev environment) -->
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="@bool/branch_io_test_mode" />
<!-- Branch install referrer tracking -->
<receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="@bool/branch_io_test_mode">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resValue "bool", "branch_io_test_mode", "true"
        resValue 'string', 'branch_key', '"key_live_*"'
        ...
    }
    release {
        resValue "bool", "branch_io_test_mode", "false"
        resValue 'string', 'branch_key', '"key_live_*"'
        ....
    }
```

Application onCreate:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Branch.enableDebugMode();
}
Branch.disableLogging();
Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
```

What exactly I am doing wrong? To be sure, there is no info about branch_key should be in strings on SDK setup page.

Comment: try to rebuild project it will generate string keys

Answer (score 0):

So a fed days after I got my fault.

Depending on build I neither set `io.branch.sdk.TestMode` to `true` or `false`. So when app compiled with `TestMode true`, Branch looked for Test key but not production key.

So actually my gradle shoud looks like:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resValue "bool", "branch_io_test_mode", "true"
        resValue 'string', 'branch_key', '"key_test_*"'
        ...
    }
    release {
        resValue "bool", "branch_io_test_mode", "false"
        resValue 'string', 'branch_key', '"key_live_*"'
        ....
    }
```